# logrotate doesn't work even if status shows that the logrotate run on my files

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, logrotate

hello guys i have a problem with my logrotate, in the status it shows me that the logrotate run on my files but no logrotate is done each day i don't know why.

can someone help please ?

I also need to mention that my logs size are 50M.

here is my nginx file that i put in /etc/logrotate.d folder

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 644 abdel abdel
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1 &
        endscript
}
```

when executing each day logrotate in debug mode i'm having this message each time with the date change ofcourse:

```
considering log /var/log/nginx/error.log
  Now: 2023-10-10 10:27
  Last rotated at 2023-10-10 00:00
  log does not need rotating (log has been rotated at 2023-10-10 0:0, that is not day ago yet)
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated
```

Comment: What did you look at to determine the log had NOT been rotated? What did you find?

Comment: my access.log and error.log are not been rotated in my nginx log folder. the command cat /var/lib/logrotate/status shows me each day the text that i put in my previous response. maybe is there a permission problem or something, my nginx log folder have 755 permission, my log file have 644 on them with the user abdel. maybe logrotate can't update this files because they only have 644 no ?

Comment: no one can help ?

Comment: At first glance, it appears that this is not a technical support service for end users, and it is also not your preferred option to be patient. However - please share `ls -lh /var/log/nginx/*.log` moreover `cat /etc/logrotate.conf` . And the told error indicates that the file is not at least 24 hours old, since you tried it 10 hours ago.

Comment: i kept testing for 72 hours, same message each day but the files doesn't get rotated. but thanks anyway `-rwxrwxrwx 1 abdel abdel 48M oct.  12 17:09 access.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abdel abdel 196K oct.  12 17:09 error.log`

Comment: when doing logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/nginx the end of my file contain this error: error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate/status.tmp: Permission denied
,can this be the problem ?

Comment: You should not give a log file (or any file for that matter) 777 permissions.

Comment: i just did it to test if the problem was from the permission

Comment: still the same problem even with 777 permissions, this is really weird, i have no error in my /var/log/syslog, the -f rotate successfully my files, but with the cron that get executed each day at midnight nothing happen on the files